# openUrl is not working when I using deluge function in zoho CRM

Tags: crm, zoho, zoho-deluge

**
I am trying to open url mention in openURL funtion in Zoho crm usig deluge but not able to succeed.
**

```
toReturn = "";
criteria = "Phone:equals:".concat(phone_number.toString());
response = zoho.crm.searchRecords(module,criteria);
if(1 < response.size())
{
    toReturn = "Ambiguous";
}
else if(0 == response.size())
{
    toReturn = "None";
}
else
{
    toReturn = response.get(0).get("Full_Name");
    openUrl("https://crm.zoho.in/crm/org60010034102/tab/Leads/" + response.get(0).get("id"),"same window");
}
info toReturn;
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing. Did you try `info response;`?

If its an OK response then this should work, but if its an error `1 < response.size()` will be triggered because errors have a size of 4. Try this or enter some invalid module name:

```
err_sample = {"code":"INVALID_MODULE","details":{},"message":"the module name given seems to be invalid","status":"error"};
info err_sample.size();
```

To handle success and error in this case you need to do something like this:

```
if (!isEmpty(response) && isNull(response.get(0)) && !isNull(response.get("code"))) {
  // handle error
}

if (!isEmpty(response) && !isNull(response.get(0)) &&  !isNull(response.get(0).get("id"))) {
  // handle success
}
```

If its just a matter of the url failing to open when you click 'Save & Execute' in the Function editor, I don't think you can do this from the code editor. I've tried a bunch of different ways and I could not get a url to open. If not, how is the function being called?